# How to get points around one point buffer area in a table

Tags: sql, buffer

I have many points in a table. I want to show points near one point. Buffer area can be 10 or 100 in SQL Server using SQL query.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates. All coding questions are expected to contain code. Please [Edit] the question to contain your best effort and give an indication of the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have a unique identifier column in your table. Here I called it `id`, and also refer to the table as `my_table`. I also assume that the point of interest has an `id` of `1`

```
/* Get the point of interest's geometry and save it in a common table expression */
WITH point_of_interest AS (
    SELECT
        geom
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        id = 1
)

/* Select everything from all the other points if they are within 100m */
SELECT
    mt.*
FROM
    my_table AS mt,
    point_of_interest AS poi
WHERE
    id != 1 -- Don't return the point of interest itself
    AND
    ST_DWithin(poi.geom, mt.geom, 100) -- Return only the points within 100 m
```